# How to save each key/data of one String which has several key/data with shared prefence?

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

Hello I have in input a String come from a read of all my sharedpreference key and data all mixed ( listString, String, int etc).

Here is my input
    String :

```
  " 
    michel            // key
    0                 // origin => int data

    Paul              // key
    15                // origin => String data

    Myke              // key
    05/03/2020        // origin => ListString data

    Myke              // key
    22/04/2020        // origin => ListString data
    "
```

I search to assign each key/data to the good sharedpreference, and programatically because I can't anticipate the order of each key, several can be not in the list because user don't save a certain function.

Here is the Ouput that I expect

```
(prefs.setInt('michel,0'));
(prefs.setString('paul,15'));
(prefs.setListString('Myke,[05/03/2020,22/04/2020]'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your data into json format through a model class, which will preserve datatypes of each variable and put it in shared-pref as key-value pair, when you want to fetch data you need to deserialize into object and viceverse when saving it.

Comment: Thank you, yes I start to look like JSON but I'm an epic noob, it's so headache to understand -_- Have you a simple example ?

Comment: you can use quicktype extension in vscode, which will automatically generate model class for you, with fromJson and toJson method, which you can use to serialize and deserialize data.

Comment: :( I use android studio

Comment: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11415-flutterjsonbeanfactory try this library for generating model classes in android studio.

Comment: Thank you, I will test this afternoon. I don't know If I will understand somethings, it's all new world :)

Comment: when you said "convert your data into JSON format" it's my one string with all mixed data/key, or I need to convert the save method ? My app is already in production,  I want to be compatible with my actual method of save key and data.

Comment: You need to create a model class which will preserve the datatypes of your jsonresponse such as array,list,int,string. this model class will help in deserialization, which is basically converting stored string into model object, which you can use to get data.